# Make asynchronous request inside a component while using Redux and Redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

This is primarily a React architecture question.

At the company, we are using React + Redux for state management and Redux-Saga for Async requests. If a component needs some data from Back-end and I only need that specific data only in that component, not anywhere else, is that okay if I make a request inside that component, not with Redux Saga?

The reason that I thought it might be better is that taking everything to Redux might be unnecessary, and only we need to use Redux when a state needs to be globally available since multiple components need to use it. On the other hand, I think it might not be the best practice to make an Async request inside a component while there is already a solution, which is Redux-saga.

To sum up, I'll be grateful if someone explains if it is a good practice to use Async Request inside a component(like a regular fetch without using Saga) while a Redux-Saga(Or Redux-Thunk) solution is already available.

This is a React architecture question and doesn't need any code.